# Add product to cart by url in magento 2

Tags: product, cart, addtocart

On the configuration page, I define the product id, now I need to call the URL: http://localhost: 3000/custom point/secret/addprizeproduct in the browser and add this product to the cart - this is necessary so that if a prize product is defined on the site, the user can click on the link and add the item to cart. How can you make this in Magento 2?

Comment: Have you try anything for this or not yet?

Comment: Not yet, i have not idea!